# Change printer driver crash

Tags: drivers, printing, crash

In Ubuntu 20, I have installed the HP Laserjet 107A printer drivers, but when I open the printer settings to select the new driver, the search loops and crashes.
This screen remains for some time and then the message appears that the application does not respond and requires forced exit.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuEZt.png)

Anyone know how I can unlock the search?
Or if there is an alternative to the system-config-printer?

Other info
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.11.0-37-generic

Comment: What is your full Ubuntu version? What is the full model number of your HP device? I can' t find Laserjet 107A on https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index .

Comment: I don't read italian, but 1 phrase jumped out of the screenshot: "Fornire il file PPD", which translate.google.com says is "Provide the PPD file". The Postscript Printer Description file data is searched through your printer's Model Number. @N0rbert suggests that you have misread your model number.

Comment: What does `sudo lshw -short` say your printer model is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here while trying to install a Konica-Minolta magicolor 1650EN. That was working fine in Xenial 16.04. Then happen the switch the the GNOME in Focal 20.04 and bing ! Impossible to select any PPD file, as the GNOME settings window crash repeatidly ...
Thumbs down for Ubuntu. The system is unworkable, until someone devise a command line way to install a printer properly.

At the end I found a solution :

Click on Additional Printer Settings ... button and select your printer. in my case magicolor-1650 then right click on it and select Properties.

On the line Device URI click change

Select --> Add Network Printer

Connection should be : AppSocket/HP Jet-Direct

Host : 192.168.1.51 (compute here the IP address og the printer)
Port Number : 9100

Which is Device URL : http://192.168.1.50:9100

Don't try to install the PPD by clicking on Make and Model Change button ... It will crash everytime there ...

Go back to the choices available in the GNOME Settings for the printer magicolor-1650 clickiing on the wheeled cirecle and set the printing options like pages etc ... Then click on Printer Details and click on the Install PPD File button ... Select the PPD you have previously downloded on your system from the manufacturer website.

And that's it. T have access to defined printers on your system you have to go back to the Additional Printer Settings. From where you can priint a Test Page.